# Access object.param in parent context handlebars.js

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

Not able to get parent object's param value

```
{{#each myObject.details}}
  <span class="marginL15 pull-left hidden-xs">
    <a href="
      /rates
      /{{../port_data.name}}
      /{{../port_data.name}}
      /{{name}}
      /{{port_code}}
    ">
      {{name}}
    </a>
  </span>
{{/each}}
```

My object is of format

```
{
    "meta_title": "fw",
    "port_data": {
        "display_name": "Rajkot (INRAJ), Rajkot, India",
        "name": "Rajkot",
        "port_code": "INRAJ"
    },
    "details": [
        {
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "58f04ef3c0a35f10b7cc08fa"
            },
            "display_name": "Sokhna(Al Sokhna) (EGSOK), Suez, Egypt",
            "name": "Sokhna(Al Sokhna)",
            "port_code": "EGSOK"
        },
        {
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "58ff42cfc0a35f493be68031"
            },
            "display_name": "Rouyn Noranda Airport - CAYUY (YUY), Canada, usa",
            "name": "Rouyn Noranda Airport - CAYUY",
            "port_code": "YUY"
        },
        {
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "58f1c6e9c0a35f2d16dd4f44"
            },
            "display_name": "Sharjah (AESHJ), Sharjah, United Arab Emirates",
            "name": "Sharjah",
            "port_code": "AESHJ"
        }
    ]
}
```

Also tried `{{@root.port_data.name}}` but to no use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When passing `myObject.details` to the `{{#each}}` helper, you pass only the referenced array stored in the `details` field of `myObject` variable - there is no way to look up to something stored in `../`, as there's nothing there.

What you could do:

```
{{#myObject}}
  {{#each details}}
  <span class="marginL15 pull-left hidden-xs">
    <a href="/rates
      /{{../port_data.name}}
      /{{name}}
      /{{port_code}}
    ">
      {{name}}
    </a>
  </span>
  {{/each}}
{{/myObject}}
```

It gives you an access to the whole `myObject` variable one scope above the `{{#each}}` loop.